# How to Specify Text Box to Sign on PDF via API/SDK?

Tags: docusignapi

I have a white-text on a white-background **text box** on a PDF. The text in that text box is set to "`<signature>`".  This is the area on the PDF that I want a signer's signature to go.

Please note, this is not a TEXT FIELD, but is a TEXT BOX. They're different things in Adobe PDF. For one thing, text boxes only have text and don't have actual field names like fields do.

I **don't** want to specific X and Y coordinates of this textbox.  I **don't** want to use a DocuSign template. I do want to use our pre-defined text box. I do want to define the signature area entirely using the API/SDK, associating it to my text box.

This is what I've tried:

I'm using the eSign model from the SDK.  I instantiated a new DocuSign.eSign.Model.SignHere object.  Do I need to associate that sign here tab somehow to my text box on the PDF?  I've tried setting each of the properties seperately (like below), but did not get the result I expected. Again, I want to associate a DocuSign.eSign.Model.SignHere tab with a pre-defined textbox on my PDF called.

```
var SignHereTab = new DocuSign.eSign.Model.SignHere();
SignHereTab.TabId = "<signature>";
SignHereTab.Name = "<signature>";
SignHereTab.AnchorCaseSensitive = "<signature>";
SignHereTab.CustomTabId = "<signature>";
```

Or, **am I going about this all wrong**? If I can't do this with a TEXT BOX, can I do it with TEXT FIELD? If it's better to use a FIELD, what code do I use to associate a sign here tab with a field? Again, I'd rather not use X/Y or Templates.

Comment: Which DocuSign SDK are you using?

Comment: Looks like it's possibly Node?

Comment: I am using the "DocuSign.eSign.dll by DocuSign" NuGet package for C#. Version 2.0.6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do I understand correctly that this is what you want to accomplish?

- Use the API to create an Envelope, with the PDF you specify as the document
- Have a ***SignHere*** tab automatically placed in the document based on where the string `<signature>` appears in the PDF

If that's the case, then you'll want to use what DocuSign refers to as **anchor text** -- this is a string that exists in the document as normal text (i.e.,, *not* *within a text box*, but rather, as normal text on the page).  The "**Get the Document to be Signed**" section of [this page](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/guide/usage/request_a_signature.html) provides a description of how to use anchor text (and even provides a sample doc that contains anchor text). An excerpt from that page:

```
Open Mutual_NDA.pdf in a PDF viewer. Search for the strings “signer1name”, “signer1sig”, and “signer1date”. You’ll notice that the search matches but that the text is not visible. These strings are regular text in the document. Their text color has been set to white, so they can’t be see in the document. But DocuSign can find them, and use them as anchor text to place the tabs (the signature, name, and date fields).
```

So, simply add the text string `<signature>` as white text (on white background) within your PDF.  Then when specifying the **SignHere** tab in the "Create Envelope" API request, set the following properties for that tab:

```
"recipients": {
    "signers": [
        {
            "roleName": "Signer1",
            "recipientId": "1",
            "name": "John Doe",
            "email": "johnDoe@test.com",
            "tabs": {
                "signHereTabs": [
                    {
                        "anchorString": "<signature>",
                        "anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent": true,
                        "documentId": "1", 
                        "optional": false, 
                        "tabLabel": "Signature"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

When used within a "Create Envelope" request (`POST https://{{env}}.docusign.net/restapi//v2/accounts/{{accountId}}/envelopes`), the JSON above will result in a (required) ***SignHere*** tab being automatically placed for recipient *John Doe* anywhere that the string `<signature>` appears in the document.

(I'm not very familiar with the node SDK, but I imagine that knowing what properties need to be set will get you going in the right direction.)

---

UPDATE #1

---

If it's important that the signature appear inside a textbox on the PDF, you can still accomplish this using anchor text. For example, simply place the anchor text string (ex: ) in the PDF just below the textbox where you want the signature tag to appear, the specify the **anchorYOffset** property and the **anchorUnits** property to tell DocuSign where you want the signature tab to appear relative to the position of the anchor string. In that example, here's the structure of the signature tab in the API request:

```
"signHereTabs": [
    {
        "anchorString": "<signature>",
        "anchorXOffset": "0", 
        "anchorYOffset": "-10",
        "anchorUnits": "pixels",
        "anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent": true,
        "documentId": "1", 
        "optional": false, 
        "tabLabel": "Signature"
    }
]
```

Finally (for your reference), here's the full list of the tab properties related to anchor strings:

[image]

Comment: The oddity to me that I cannot use TEXT BOX text.  Meaning, if I add a text box to the PDF and give it text like <signature> and make it white-on-white, the API will tell me that "The specified Anchor Tab string was not found in the document."  


You're update 1 makes me think that I still have to add "real" anchor text to the PDF, and I cannot use JUST the text box text. Can you confirm that I can or cannot use JUST text in the text box as anchor text? From my investigation, the API cannot find anchor text if the text is ONLY in the text box.

Comment: That's correct -- DocuSign will not read/detect anchor text that's located inside any form element (i.e., text box, drop down list, etc.) within the PDF.  For DocuSign to read/detect an anchor string, it has to be located directly on the page itself (i.e., not within any form element).

Comment: I agree your answer seems sufficient - I cannot use a TEXT BOX.  Can I use a TEXT FIELD?  Both are things in Adobe PDF.

Comment: I don't believe a Text Field will work either.  You simply want to add text to the document itself (i.e., not inside any type of form element) -- as described here:  https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/using/edit-text-pdfs.html#add_new_text_to_a_pdf.  (If you think the answer is sufficient, please mark it as "accepted" so that others may benefit from the info in the future. Thanks!)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you'll be able to do this using a text box instead of text field. See this page on the REST API guide:

---

[Document Parameters](https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/RESTAPIGuide.htm#REST%20API%20References/Document%20Parameters.htm)

---

Only the FieldTypes and FieldProperties listed below are extrapolated from the forms:

```
FieldTypes that are extrapolated are: CheckBox, DateTime, ListBox, Numeric, Radio, Text, Signature, and Password.
FieldProperties that are extrapolated are: ReadOnly, Required, MaxLength, Positions, and Initial Data.
```

There's an example of how to do the transform in the Dev Center website (you need to use composite templates) but as mentioned I think you need to use text fields for it to work.  See the Transform PDF Fields section:

[Transform PDF Fields](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/explore/features/stick-etabs#tab-positioning)

Comment: It seems like the API does not search text box for anchor text.  Meaning, if I add the anchor text inside of a white-on-white text box, it will not find that text.  The API responds with "The specified Anchor Tab string was not found in the document."  It does seem to work if I set the anchor string to any text found on the actual page (meaning, not inside of a text box).