# How to use PDF Form Field Name for Tab Placement using DocuSign API

Tags: docusignapi

I am trying to add the signature tab on a pdf document using DocuSign. Currently , I used Anchor Strings for Tab Placement (Stick-etabs). Now I have a PDF form that has placeholders (please see image below) for placing the signature tabs.

What I am looking for is that DocuSign has anything that let me add the signature tab by looking at the form filed **Candidate Legal Name** and place the signature tab at that place.

[image]

Currently, I am using the following code for anchor code tab placement

```
....
....

"tabs": {
                    "signHereTabs": [
                        {
                            "documentId": "2",
                            "pageNumber":"1",
                            "anchorString": "//@placeholder",
                            "name": "Full Name",
                            "optional": "false",
                            "recipientId": "1"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "email": "fullName@gmail.com",
                "name": "PSignature",
                "recipientId": "2",
                "routingOrder": "2",
                "tabs": {
                    "signHereTabs": [
                        {
                            "documentId": "2",
                            "pageNumber":"1",
                            "anchorString": "//@PurchaserSignature2",
                            "name": "Purchaser Full Name",
                            "optional": "false",
                            "recipientId": "2"
                        }
                    ]
                }
```

All I am searching for is that is it possible or not.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you should be able to use "**anchor text**" to achieve what you're trying to achieve.  (i.e., you'll need to add **anchor text** to the PDF though -- there's no way to tell DocuSign to place a signature where it sees the "Candidate Legal Name" form field name.)

See the accepted Answer (including its comments) here for details about how to accomplish your goal: [How to Specify Text Box to Sign on PDF via API/SDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38798155/how-to-specify-text-box-to-sign-on-pdf-via-api-sdk/38805186#38805186)

As that answer describes -- DocuSign will not read/detect anchor text that's located *inside* any form element (i.e., text box, drop down list, etc.) within the PDF. For DocuSign to read/detect an anchor string, it has to be located directly on the page itself (i.e., not within any form element). So you'll need to add the anchor text string to the PDF above/below/beside the form field (as [text within the document itself](https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/using/edit-text-pdfs.html#add_new_text_to_a_pdf)), and then specify the **anchorXOffset** and/or **anchorYOffset** attributes in your *Create Envelope* API Request to tell DocuSign where to place the signature tab, relevant to where the anchor text exists in the document.

Comment: That is exactly I was looking for. The anchor text requires a string and I'll go by that method then. Thanks